# WAR, manifest.mf and version

Tags: java, version, manifest, war

I have a WAR file, and inside a /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF containing my product version info:

```
Implementation-Version: 1.0.0.0
```

At my index.jsp I have this code to print the version:

```
<%  
String version = com.my.Utils.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
out.print("Version: " + version);
%>
```

This code always return:

```
Version:
```

This solution is based on [this article](http://www.javablog.fr/javaspring-get-and-display-the-version-from-manifest-mf.html).

What I need to do read my version information from war manifest file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That article you link specifically mentions the second case, where you're deploying a classic web application:

```
<%
//Get version of application
java.util.Properties prop = new java.util.Properties();
prop.load(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"));
String applVersion = prop.getProperty("Implementation-Version");  
%>
<h2 class="x-panel-header"><%=applVersion%></h2>
```

The method is different depending on how your application is deployed.